# lmer output only shows satistics for 3 levels of my factor, but the factor is 4 levels

Tags: regression, mixed-model, categorical-data, lme4-nlme, missing-data

I have a factor called "condition." I am using lmer to run a regression model on condition's effect on an outcome variable called "rating."

The factor "condition" is 4 levels, the 4 conditions of my experiment. When I run lmer, the output only shows stats for 3 levels. Where is the info on the 4th level? I checked the .csv file the data is in and used str(data) to make sure the 4th level is there, and R says condition is a factor with 4 levels.

I run this code:

```
contrasts(data$condition) = c(0, 0, 1, -1)                
condition.compare.CMN_filtered_or_not <- lmer(rating~condition+(1|participant_num)+(1|sentence)+(1|speaker),data=data)
```

And get this output for the fixed effects:

Fixed effects:
Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) -0.01314    0.07437  -0.177
condition1  -0.17153    0.08266  -2.075
condition2   0.39287    0.12187   3.224
condition3  -0.16197    0.12442  -1.302

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
(Intr) cndtn1 cndtn2
condition1 -0.014
condition2 -0.050 -0.016
condition3 -0.023 -0.007 -0.026

-Where is condition 4?

Comment: It's included in the intercept

Comment: Thank you for that answer @RobertLong! I still have a question though- does included in the intercept mean that that -0.01314 value for the intercept is the same as the estimate for Condition 4, or that part of the value for the Condition 4 estimate is within that value given for the intercept?

Comment: No worries, The intercept is the expected value of the response when all covariates are at zero - or ni the case of categorical variables,, when they are at their reference levels. It's just like in the case of a single numeric predictor, the intercept is the expected value of the response when the predictor is zero (ie where it crosses the y-axis - in other words, the intercept). Hope this helps